# The size of image bytes array changed after published by ros in Android?

Tags: ros, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the problem in one of my ros-android project. In this project, I need to send the sensor messages type of compressed image which comes from the camera preview data to ros-server, however when I subscribed the topic to decode a bitmap from what I had published, I found the size of the image bytes array changed, it get bigger! And I had test this in other program environment, like C++ and C#, this problem never happened! I don't know why, and so confused about where I made a mistake that to caused this problem.

I had post my question in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45755189/messages-size-of-sensor-msgs-image-compressedimage-type-will-changed-when-publis) for help, however, it's helpless. So I have to ask the question again in here. You guys need to check for more details to visit the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45755189/messages-size-of-sensor-msgs-image-compressedimage-type-will-changed-when-publis) link. I really need your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269505/the-size-of-image-bytes-array-changed-after-published-by-ros-in-android?/) by [Zorcs](https://answers.ros.org/users/29838/zorcs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK! I got the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45755189/messages-size-of-sensor-msgs-image-compressedimage-type-will-changed-when-publis/45910894#45910894) by myself, ps, I'm really need to develop the good habit of checking API always before ask question!

---

Originally posted by [Zorcs](https://answers.ros.org/users/29838/zorcs/) with karma: 16 on 2017-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-28**:
It would be nice if you could clarify *what* the actual answer was, instead of linking to your SO question (which also only links to the API documentation).

**Comment by [Zorcs](https://answers.ros.org/users/29838/zorcs/) on 2017-08-28**:
@gvdhoorn  I had re-edit my answer! Thanks for your suggestions!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-28**:
I actually meant it would be nice if you could edit your answer *here* on ROS Answers. Not on StackOverflow.